# Serial communication through C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, buffer, serial-communication

While reading from serial port I am using 
serialport.read(xyz,0,4)
where xyz is a byte array.

Question 1: while doing so, does the data which I have read gets deleted from the buffer of the serial port? Or is there a pointer which gets incremented?

Question 2:

```
private void moduleSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender,System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
.
.
.
}
```

If new data is received when the code for previous data is executed, will the event of data received be triggered?

I found that when my system ran for few hours following thing was taking place:
When new data was transmitted, it was received on the serial port but the computer processed previously sent data. So I am doubting that the data stays in buffer and is executed on next datareceived event.

Can someone please help me out.
Appreciate your help.
thanks

Comment: "Can someone please help me out?"**What exactly is your question?  You have not provided any code.  This should be two seperate questions and they should both have code that goes with them.  A serial communication has a buffer, you read 4 bytes, those 4 bytes is sent to you.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data stays in the buffer until you read it.  Simply handling a `DataReceived` event does not cause the data to be dequeued, you actually have to read it.  If you read less than the entire buffer, then next time the `DataReceived` event occurs, you will read the old leftovers before the new data.

Comment: Thanks I got answers to my question. The only thing I want now is:
On data received event I want to read bytes till the buffer gets empty. I am not able to paste the code here.. may b i'll try to give the url. thanks

Comment: @Akshay: Have a look at the `BytesToRead` property, which tells you how many bytes are in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve yout problem

http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/04/c-serial-port-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow this sample of code

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SerialPort-Windows-Forms-a43f208e

Regards.